# How to re-add a missing font

Tags: windows-7, fonts, microsoft-office-2010

I recently upgraded from Office 2007 to 2010, and that went fairly smoothly.  However, afterwards, my Calibri font was gone, so my Word and Outlook started using the next available font in the list... Comic Sans!

I browsed to Control Panel > Fonts, and saw that there was no longer a Calibri listing.

I know that one way to recover a missing font is to just copy the missing font files from another computer.  In my case, the four files I needed were:

```
calibri.ttf,  //regular 
calibrib.ttf, //bold
calibrii.ttf, //italics
calibriz.ttf, //bold and italics
```

However, once I attempted to copy-and-paste these files to my computer, I realized these files were already on my problem computer; they never really got erased.  I don't know why they aren't working in Office, and they aren't listed in Control Panel > Fonts.

Comment: i don't like calibri, as new ms office developers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once I realized the files were already on my computer, I launched a command prompt, and browsed to c:\windows\fonts.  I typed the name of the first file I needed (Calibri.ttf), and it launched a window for the font.  At the top of the window are two buttons; Print and Install.  The Install button successfully re-installed the font on my computer.  I repeated this process for the 3 remaining versions of Calibri, restarted my Office apps, and I've back in business ever since.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem w Office 2016 / 365 - DISPLAY (only) was showing up as another font.

MS Level 2 tech said it was a current issue w an Office update

But not giving up ...
From the above, I downloaded and reinstalled Calibri and it is all fixed.